# Backpropagation neural network

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scipy, neural-network, classification

I need to use Backpropagation Neural Netwrok for multiclass classification purposes in my application. I have found [this code](http://danielfrg.com/blog/2013/07/03/basic-neural-network-python/#disqus_thread) and try to adapt it to my needs. It is based on the lections of Machine Learning in Coursera from Andrew Ng. 
I have tested it in IRIS dataset and achieved good results (accuracy of classification around 0.96), whereas on my real data I get terrible results. I assume there is some implementation error, because the data is very simple. But I cannot figure out what exactly is the problem.

What are the parameters that it make sense to adjust?
I tried with:

- number of units in hidden layer
- generalization parameter (lambda)
- number of iterations for minimization function

Built-in minimization function used in this code is pretty much confusing me. It is used just once, as @goncalopp has mentioned in comment. Shouldn't it iteratively update the weights? How it can be implemented?

Here is my training data (target class is in the last column):

---

```
65535, 3670, 65535, 3885, -0.73, 1
65535, 3962, 65535, 3556, -0.72, 1
65535, 3573, 65535, 3529, -0.61, 1
3758, 3123, 4117, 3173, -0.21, 0
3906, 3119, 4288, 3135, -0.28, 0
3750, 3073, 4080, 3212, -0.26, 0
65535, 3458, 65535, 3330, -0.85, 2
65535, 3315, 65535, 3306, -0.87, 2
65535, 3950, 65535, 3613, -0.84, 2
65535, 32576, 65535, 19613, -0.35, 3
65535, 16657, 65535, 16618, -0.37, 3
65535, 16657, 65535, 16618, -0.32, 3
```

The dependencies are so obvious, I think it should be so easy to classify it...

But results are terrible. I get accuracy of 0.6 to 0.8. This is absolutely inappropriate for my application. Can someone please point out possible improvements I could make in order to achieve better results.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import math

class NN_1HL(object):

    def __init__(self, reg_lambda=0, epsilon_init=0.12, hidden_layer_size=25, opti_method='TNC', maxiter=500):
        self.reg_lambda = reg_lambda
        self.epsilon_init = epsilon_init
        self.hidden_layer_size = hidden_layer_size
        self.activation_func = self.sigmoid
        self.activation_func_prime = self.sigmoid_prime
        self.method = opti_method
        self.maxiter = maxiter

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

    def sigmoid_prime(self, z):
        sig = self.sigmoid(z)
        return sig * (1 - sig)

    def sumsqr(self, a):
        return np.sum(a ** 2)

    def rand_init(self, l_in, l_out):
        self.epsilon_init = (math.sqrt(6))/(math.sqrt(l_in + l_out))
        return np.random.rand(l_out, l_in + 1) * 2 * self.epsilon_init - self.epsilon_init

    def pack_thetas(self, t1, t2):
        return np.concatenate((t1.reshape(-1), t2.reshape(-1)))

    def unpack_thetas(self, thetas, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels):
        t1_start = 0
        t1_end = hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)
        t1 = thetas[t1_start:t1_end].reshape((hidden_layer_size, input_layer_size + 1))
        t2 = thetas[t1_end:].reshape((num_labels, hidden_layer_size + 1))
        return t1, t2

    def _forward(self, X, t1, t2):
        m = X.shape[0]
        ones = None
        if len(X.shape) == 1:
            ones = np.array(1).reshape(1,)
        else:
            ones = np.ones(m).reshape(m,1)

        # Input layer
        a1 = np.hstack((ones, X))

        # Hidden Layer
        z2 = np.dot(t1, a1.T)
        a2 = self.activation_func(z2)
        a2 = np.hstack((ones, a2.T))

        # Output layer
        z3 = np.dot(t2, a2.T)
        a3 = self.activation_func(z3)
        return a1, z2, a2, z3, a3

    def function(self, thetas, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, reg_lambda):
        t1, t2 = self.unpack_thetas(thetas, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels)

        m = X.shape[0]
        Y = np.eye(num_labels)[y]

        _, _, _, _, h = self._forward(X, t1, t2)
        costPositive = -Y * np.log(h).T
        costNegative = (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - h).T
        cost = costPositive - costNegative
        J = np.sum(cost) / m

        if reg_lambda != 0:
            t1f = t1[:, 1:]
            t2f = t2[:, 1:]
            reg = (self.reg_lambda / (2 * m)) * (self.sumsqr(t1f) + self.sumsqr(t2f))
            J = J + reg
        return J

    def function_prime(self, thetas, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, reg_lambda):
        t1, t2 = self.unpack_thetas(thetas, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels)

        m = X.shape[0]
        t1f = t1[:, 1:]
        t2f = t2[:, 1:]
        Y = np.eye(num_labels)[y]

        Delta1, Delta2 = 0, 0
        for i, row in enumerate(X):
            a1, z2, a2, z3, a3 = self._forward(row, t1, t2)

            # Backprop
            d3 = a3 - Y[i, :].T
            d2 = np.dot(t2f.T, d3) * self.activation_func_prime(z2)

            Delta2 += np.dot(d3[np.newaxis].T, a2[np.newaxis])
            Delta1 += np.dot(d2[np.newaxis].T, a1[np.newaxis])

        Theta1_grad = (1 / m) * Delta1
        Theta2_grad = (1 / m) * Delta2

        if reg_lambda != 0:
            Theta1_grad[:, 1:] = Theta1_grad[:, 1:] + (reg_lambda / m) * t1f
            Theta2_grad[:, 1:] = Theta2_grad[:, 1:] + (reg_lambda / m) * t2f

        return self.pack_thetas(Theta1_grad, Theta2_grad)

    def fit(self, X, y):
        num_features = X.shape[0]
        input_layer_size = X.shape[1]
        num_labels = len(set(y))

        theta1_0 = self.rand_init(input_layer_size, self.hidden_layer_size)
        theta2_0 = self.rand_init(self.hidden_layer_size, num_labels)
        thetas0 = self.pack_thetas(theta1_0, theta2_0)

        options = {'maxiter': self.maxiter}
        _res = optimize.minimize(self.function, thetas0, jac=self.function_prime, method=self.method, 
                                 args=(input_layer_size, self.hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, 0), options=options)

        self.t1, self.t2 = self.unpack_thetas(_res.x, input_layer_size, self.hidden_layer_size, num_labels)

        np.savetxt("weights_t1.txt", self.t1, newline="\n")
        np.savetxt("weights_t2.txt", self.t2, newline="\n")

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.predict_proba(X).argmax(0)

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        _, _, _, _, h = self._forward(X, self.t1, self.t2)
        return h


##################
# IR data        #
##################
values = np.loadtxt('infrared_data.txt', delimiter=', ', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])

targets = np.loadtxt('infrared_data.txt', delimiter=', ', dtype=(int), usecols=[5])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(values, targets, test_size=0.4)
nn = NN_1HL()
nn.fit(values, targets)
print("Accuracy of classification: "+str(accuracy_score(y_test, nn.predict(X_test))))
```

Comment: Could you print out the accuracy on the training set, too? If (as @goncalopp suggested) your training dataset is too small, you would see good accuracy on the training set, but bad predictions on the test set. Best way to improve this is by using a larger training set, second best by using a simpler model (your data looks as if a simple kNN or linear classifier might work; I think `reg_lambda` is a "weight decay" term, setting that > 0 might also help)

Comment: @nikie note that backpropagated FFNN are typically initialized with random weights. IIRC, if the learning rate is slow, the accuracy in the training set can still be low even after training the network.

Comment: @goncalopp: You mean training can get stuck at a local minimum? Then the training error would be high too, that's why I asked for it. If that's the case, using a simpler model (weight decay, fewer hidden neurons) should help too, right?

Comment: @nikie I have added the following print:
`print("Accuracy of classification on the trainings set: " +str(accuracy_score(targets, nn.predict(values))))`
and get the accuracy between 0.6 and 0.8 depending on the random initialization. I will try to change regularization parameter and reduce the number of nodes in hidden layer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correctly normalizing the data solved the problem. I used preprocessing module from sklearn. Here is example:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                    [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1., -1.]])


min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
print(X_train_minmax)

X_test = np.array([[ -3., -1.,  4.]])
X_test_minmax = min_max_scaler.transform(X_test)
print(X_test_minmax)
```

And the output is:

```
[[ 0.5     0.      1.    ]
 [ 1.      0.5     0.3333]
 [ 0.      1.      0.    ]]


[[-1.5     0.      1.6667]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is that **your training dataset is very small**.

Since you're using `scipy.optimize.minimize` instead of the usual iterative gradient descent, I think it's also likely you're [**overfitting** your model to your training data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). Possibly a iterative algorithm works better, here. Don't forget to carefully **monitor the validation error**.

If you try backpropagation with gradient descent, notice that, depending on the parameters used on backpropagation, neural networks take a while to converge

You can try to feed the network the same training data multiple times or tweak the [learning rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Phase_2:_Weight_update) but ideally you should use more diverse data.

Comment: What does it mean in my case "tweak the learning rate"? I use not a gradient descent but built-in optimization function to minimize the cost function with the weights in theta.

So basically I see only following parameters to adjust:
number of units in hidden layer, maximum number of iterations for minimization function, and regularisation parameter to avoid overfitting. Btw how to choose this regularization parameter? What are reasonable values?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with `scipy.optimize`. After a quick look over the code, it seems you're doing that minimization just once. That will probably lead to [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) to training data. You'll want to use a method that *gradually* reaches the desired behaviour, and carefully monitor the validation error, so you can stop as soon as you start overfitting. [Here's typical training/validation fitness curves for a backprop. FFNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting#mediaviewer/File:Overfitting_svg.svg)

Comment: I am just learning myself. Overfitting means that the hypothesis fit's "too good" to training data and doesn't generalize, is that right? But in my case the network is not able to classify even training samples (just about 80% of them), so I thought it is not an overfitting problem.

Minimization function is confusing to me also. It has parameter maxiter which I can vary, but it doesn't improve the results though. I think I will have to find the way to implement normal gradient descent minimization